# Find output current for a non-ideal op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

This is a past paper question. I can find a expression for output current (\$I_O\$) if the op-amps are ideal but I cannot understand how to solve it if the op-amps are non-ideal.

[image]

Comment: Hint: instead of infinite open-loop gain, assume the open-loop gain is finite. This makes the difference between the in(+) and in(-) voltages significant, and dependent on the open-loop gain. This has practical application because real op-amp open-loop gain decreases at higher frequency.

Comment: "Non-ideal" can mean: Finite input and output impedances, finite and freqency-dependent gain, offset currents and offset voltages,...so - what do you intend to consider?

Comment: NB: if you take into account all these "defects", calculus would be, quasi, not practical by hand ... So, write down all equations needed and "solve" the system. The "finite and frequency-dependent gain" would be the first taken into account for our "modern" opamp ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE&O,

> but I cannot understand how to solve it if the op-amps are non-ideal.

For example, here is a Maple sheet ("brute force") for this case.
One can also take the "limit" for all functions when **Ao -> infinity**, for the **ideal** case.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The shown circuit can be analyzed using superposition. For this purpose you can use the available gain expressions for inverting as well as non-inverting opamp circuits.
These well-known expressions (based on ideal opamps) can easily be extended for real opamps with finite (fixed) open-loop gain Aol=Aoo resp. frequency-dependent first order open-loop gain Aol=Aoo/(1+w/wo):

Closed-loop gain **Acl=H_in/[(1/Aol)+H_f]**

with feedback factor: **H_f=R1/(R1+R2)** and  forward factor H_in.

(1) Inverter: **H_in=R2/(R1+R2)**

(2) Non-inverter: **H_in=1**

Comment 1: R1 from signal input to the inv. terminal; R2 between opamp output and inv. terminal.

Comment 2 (EDIT): H_in has a negative sign.